# strip any hyperlinks and text within from piece of text

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking to know how I can strip any hyperlink < a > tags from within some text - the whole lot including the text/image whatever is being linked before the end < / a > tag.

E.g.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Click here</a>        
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="http://stackoverflow.com" alt = "blah"></a>
```

ie. remove the whole lot.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a regex replace?

Comment: @Jay - I don't think that will satisfy his requirements, because it will not catch the content between the start and end of the anchor tag.

Comment: Strong is the power of regular expressions. Under estimate them you should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, this should work

```
string linksRemoved = Regex.Replace(withLinks, @"</?(a|A).*>", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory "don't use regex to parse html" warning: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I would recommend either converting to XHTML and using xPath or taking a look at the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to do this.  I have used both methods for parsing/modifying html in the past and they are far more flexible/robust than using regex.

Here is an example that should get you started with HtmlAgilityPack:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
 {
    // Do stuff!
 }
 doc.Save("file.htm");
```

Comment: +1 for HTMLAgilityPack. Regex might suffice for this case but for more complex HTML parsing, HTMLAgilityPack is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regular expression to replace your tags. My regex isn't the best but this should get you close.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
     input, 
     @"<a[^>]*?>.*?</a>", 
     string.Empty);
```